# How to use Grab tool at multiple objects at same time?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpt, zbrush

I am new to blender. Is there any way to sculpt different object at same time. Just like zbrush Transpose master or T-Pose tool

Comment: ... temporarily Join objects?

Comment: Yes i can do that but its a lenthy process and all though i have to apply modifiers first

Comment: I would say probably not. Objects are separate for a reason.

Comment: No. Just for temporary basis just like zbrush Transpose master